# Не создается сокет mysql

Tags: mysql, битрикс, centos

Загрузили образ вирт. машины(Битрикс). Воссоздали все тех. требования(ОЗУ,ПЗУ и т.д.). При включении не запускается MySQL 
mysql satus

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Сокета соответственно нет по адресу который прописан в конфиге(my.cnf)

```
/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

При перезагрузке должен как бы создавать, но этого не происходит.
В чем ошибка?Куда копать?

```
service mysqld status
root@master1 ~]# service mysqld status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2018-05-31 14:30:09 +03; 12min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 6410 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, st                                                     atus=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6392 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
May 31 14:30:09 master1 systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.



ps -AlF | grep mysql
0 S root      9700  9213  0  80   0 - 28165 pipe_w   972   2 15:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста вывод команды `ps -AlF | grep mysql`. Ну и такой мелкий вопрос, а свободного места у вас достаточно?

Comment: `[root@master1 ~]# ps -AlF | grep mysql
0 S root      9700  9213  0  80   0 - 28165 pipe_w   972   2 15:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
` 
место достаточно.

Comment: ну так сервер не запускается, вот и сокета нет. смотрите логи сервера и устраняйте причину ошибки, из-за которой он не запускается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в нехватке физической памяти.